# Mapping EF 4.1 code-first models to database tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have been trying the model-first method when designing my application. We usually like to add a prefix to our tables in larger databases so it is easier to find stuff. For example:

- sc_ = Shopping cart tables
- wb_ = Water billing tables
- ea_ = Employment Application tables

The class I have setup looks like this so far.

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TransactionItem> TransactionItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Response> Response { get; set; }
}
```

Web.config (set currently for local database testing):

```
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=database" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

What do I need to change so that the Transaction object gets linked to the sc_Transactions table? I haven't seen in my searching that clarifies this.

As a second question, do I have to manually create my tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `OnModelCreating` method from `DbContext` in your `EFDbContext` class:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TransactionItem> TransactionItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Response> Response { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().MapSingleType().ToTable("someTableNameHere");
    }
}
```

See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx) post for more info.

Comment: I had to use `modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().ToTable("sc_Transaction");` instead as documented [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1651092.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` like so:

```
[Table("tblUser")]
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Or with EF 4 you can override the OnModelCreating method to map your tables, which is quite powerful thing as you can map and adjust many things at once.

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().MapSingleType().ToTable("tblUser");
    }
}
```

For more info see:

- [EF4 CF custom database mapping](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx)
- [EF keynotes from the Build2011 event (custom mappings are at about
  15 min or so)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/SAC-812T)

Comment: I like this method as well. It appears like you could use `[Column("name")]` on each field you want to rename as well.